Text Alignment Issues in the Column an rows of the tables
Hi all I have a challenge once more that I am not seeing no matter how I try or what I tried.
I tried understanding the documentation here https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Tables#Tables_with_a_fixed_width
I tried googling the error which is not clear to me no matter what I read.
Can someone help me understand what is happening here? please!
the issue:
the table sits nicely but once again something is throwing off the text within the rows
They are overlapping and I cannot seem to understand why.
So I Tired:
Applying the \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%} and \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%}functions but they are not working as I would like them to.
forgive my limited knowledge in explaining the errors as I am not sure what the terminology is called. To my knowledge
this seems to be relative to Text Alignment ** I am positive that I am wrong** hence me requesting aid to get pass this hurdle.
I posted an image to show what is happening as I am always told that I am not presenting an example. I hope this helps

I would be extremely grateful for some guidance at this stage, I am stuck and unable to move forward. Thanx in advance for acknowledging my errors AND apologies for any standards I may over look at this stage*

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lscape}

% Rotate the next page
\begin{landscape}
\pagebreak[75]
\global\pdfpageattr\expandafter{\the\pdfpageattr/Rotate 90}
% Reset table counter within each subsection
\vspace*{5mm}
\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\thesubsection.\arabic{table}}


\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{tabular}{cccccl}
\hline
\textbf{\#} &
  \textbf{Confidence} &
  \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Positive \\ (Functional\end{tabular}} &
  \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Negative\\ (No Function)\end{tabular}} &
  \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Negative \\ (Partially Functioning)\end{tabular}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Description}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{1} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{High} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{12} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}The kernel has to slide two steps to the right to touch the right side of the input (and equivalently downwards). Adding one to account for the initial ker- nel position, the output size is 3 × 3\\\\\\\end{tabular}}} \\ \cline{1-5}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Strong}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{11} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\ \cline{1-5}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Strong}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{10} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{4} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Moderate} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{8} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}(Arbitrary padding and strides) a 3 × 3\\ kernel over a 6×6 input padded \\with a 1×1 border of zeros using 2×2 strides \\(i.e., i = 6, k=3,s=2andp=1). In this case,the bottom row and right column of the zero padded input are not covered by the kernel. violence.\end{tabular}}} \\ \cline{1-5}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{5} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Moderate} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{9}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{6} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Weak} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{7} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\multirow{5}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\\\\\\To factor in zero padding (i.e., only restricting\\to s = 1), let’s consider its effect on the effective input size: padding \\with p zeros changes the effective input size from \\i to i + 2p. In the general case, Relationship 1 can then be used to infer the following relationship.\end{tabular}}} \\ \cline{1-5}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{7} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Weak}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{6}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\ \cline{1-5}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{8} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Weak}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{6}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\ \cline{1-5}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{9} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Weak}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{9}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\ \cline{1-5}
10                      & Weak                         & 0                       & 0                      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{12} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{}
\label{tab:my-table}
\end{table}
% End the rotation
\pagebreak[75]
\global\pdfpageattr\expandafter{\the\pdfpageattr/Rotate 0}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}

this is the closest I am getting but the data continues to overlap to the other rows.
help please!!!
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Stay very far away from these awful online table generators. Alls these bothersome \multicolumn{1}{|c|} make it nearly impossible to properly adjust the table to the page geometry.

And never scale elements which contain text, it will make your document look like a ransom letter.

Hey @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, thanx for responding and advising me. this is so stressful at these final stages it is not funny given my deadlines. I tried everything but I simply don't have the basic knowledge to generate it on my own ever though I am literally spending hours trying to learn but coming up empty handed. that is so not a good feeling. Any more suggestions?

where is it scale might I ask in the code? so that I'd understand the next time around.. TIA

It's probably better to place the lengthy descriptions in tablenotes below the table instead of trying to fit them inside of the table itself:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lscape}

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{}
\label{tab:my-table}
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\toprule
\thead{\#} &
  \thead{Conf.} &
  \thead{Positive \\ (Functioning)} &
  \thead{Negative\\ (No Function)} &
  \thead{Negative \\ (Partially Functioning)}\\ 
 \midrule
 1\tnote{a} & High     & 12 & 0 &  0 \\
 2\tnote{a} & Strong   & 11 & 0 &  1 \\
 3\tnote{a} & Strong   & 10 & 1 &  1 \\ 
 \midrule
 4\tnote{b} & Moderate &  8 & 2 &  2 \\
 5\tnote{b} & Moderate &  9 & 2 &  1 \\ 
 \midrule
 6\tnote{c} & Weak     &  7 & 1 &  4 \\
 7\tnote{c} & Weak     &  6 & 1 &  5 \\ 
 8\tnote{c} & Weak     &  4 & 2 &  6 \\ 
 9\tnote{c} & Weak     &  2 & 1 &  9 \\ 
10\tnote{c} & Weak     &  0 & 0 & 12 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\footnotesize
\item[a] The kernel has to slide two steps to the right to touch the right side of the input (and equivalently downwards). Adding one to account for the initial ker- nel position, the output size is 3 × 3
\item[b] (Arbitrary padding and strides) a 3 × 3 kernel over a 6×6 input padded with a 1×1 border of zeros using 2×2 strides (i.e., i = 6, k=3, s=2 and p=1). In this case,the bottom row and right column of the zero padded input are not covered by the kernel. violence.
\item[c] To factor in zero padding (i.e., only restricting to s = 1), let’s consider its effect on the effective input size: padding with p zeros changes the effective input size from i to i + 2p. In the general case, Relationship 1 can then be used to infer the following relationship.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}


ahh I see @leandris, jolly good morning to you! Thank you for responding and for your guidance. I will trying this now..Really appreciate this loads!! big hugs!!!
